# PostgreSQL grouping by day with timezone and DST

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I'm working on an existing database which date+time values are stored in `BIGINT` column (*milliseconds since EPOCH*). For each entry I can get the corresponding time zone from another table. But to make things easier to understand I will explain my problem by simulating the problem.

The timestamp `1609534800000` is equal to `2021-01-01 21:00:00` at GMT (00-00)

Now if I run the following queries (with DBeaver)

```sql
set time zone 'America/Asuncion';  -- (UTC-3)

select 
     to_timestamp(1609534800000 / 1000) as "1"
   , to_timestamp(1609534800000 / 1000) at TIME zone 'America/New_York' as "2"
   , date_trunc('day', (to_timestamp(1609534800000 / 1000) at TIME zone 'America/New_York')) as "3"
   , to_timestamp(1609534800000 / 1000) at TIME zone 'Pacific/Wake' as "4"
   , date_trunc('day', (to_timestamp(1609534800000 / 1000) at TIME zone 'Pacific/Wake')) as "5"
   , date_part('epoch', (to_timestamp(1609534800000 / 1000) at TIME zone 'Pacific/Wake')) as "6"
   , date_part('epoch', (date_trunc('day', (to_timestamp(1609534800000 / 1000) at TIME zone 'Pacific/Wake') ) ) ) as "7"
```

I'm getting

```
1                  |2                  |3                  |4                  |5                  |6         |7         |
-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|----------|----------|
2021-01-01 16:00:00|2021-01-01 16:00:00|2021-01-01 00:00:00|2021-01-02 09:00:00|2021-01-02 00:00:00|1609578000|1609545600|
```

1. **I don't understand the result at all**. According to the documentation, the function `to_timestamp` is supposed to return a `timestamp with time zone` ? In this case the time zone applied should be the one in my session `America/Asuncion` (UTC-3). If at GMT the time is `2021-01-01 21:00:00`, I should get `2021-01-01 18:00:00`. Because (`21:00 - 3h = 18:00`). Why 16h ?
2. From my understanding this result is OK as `2021-01-01 21:00:00` at UTC -5h for timezone `America/New_York` is equal to `2021-01-01 16:00`.
3. Here I'm asking the same thing as the #2 but I want to discard the time of the day. So `2021-01-01 16:00:00` is `2021-01-01 00:00:00`. The result is OK.
4. This result is still OK as `2021-01-01 21:00:00` at UTC + 12h for timezone `Pacific/Wake` is equal to `2021-01-02 09:00:00`.
   5 I'm asking the same thing as the #4 but I want to discard the time of the day. So `2021-01-02 09:00:00` is `2021-01-02 00:00:00`. The result is OK.
5. I want to extract the unix EPOCH time in seconds of this timestamp. If I well understand, the timestamp pass to the `date_part` function is now a `timestamp without time zone`. Now if I use an [online converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to convert the resulting value `1609578000` to GMT time then I'm getting `2021-01-02 9:00:00`. Which is OK for me.
6. This is the same operation as the #6 but I want the unix epoch from the beginning of the day of that local time. The resulting value `1609545600` correspond to the GMT time `2021-01-02 00:00:00`. Which **is NOT correct** as I should get `2021-01-02 12:00:00` as 'Pacific/Wake' is 12h past GMT.

(**UPDATED**)
Also why `Montreal` locale time is not correct here ? I'm supposed to have `2021-01-01 00:00:00-05`

```sql
select ((to_timestamp(1609477200000 /1000) at time zone 'America/Asuncion') at time zone 'America/Asuncion') as asuncion 
       , ((to_timestamp(1609477200000 /1000) at time zone 'America/Montreal') at time zone 'America/Montreal') as montreal

        asuncion        |        montreal
------------------------+------------------------
 2021-01-01 02:00:00-03 | 2021-01-01 02:00:00-03
```

How could I get

```
        asuncion        |        montreal
------------------------+------------------------
 2021-01-01 02:00:00-03 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00-05
```

Is there a way to see the time WITHOUT the configured session timeszone ?

*PS : My Windows OS timezone is set at `America/New_York` and I'm using PostgreSQL 10.*

Best regards,

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The one I'm using give me a `timestamp with time zone`. You can test it by doing `select pg_typeof( to_timestamp(0) )` which gives `timestamp with time zone`.

Comment: Insufficient caffeine when I wrote that, will delete comment.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver No problem ;)

In fact both versions gives a `timestamp with time zone`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't replicate 1). I get:

```
set time zone 'America/Asuncion';

select to_timestamp(1609534800000 / 1000);
      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2021-01-01 18:00:00-03
```

As to 6), you did not account for the SET timezone:

```
select date_part('epoch', date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(1609534800000 / 1000) at TIME zone 'Pacific/Wake') at TIME zone 'Pacific/Wake');
 date_part  
------------
 1609502400

select to_timestamp(1609502400);
      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2021-01-01 09:00:00-03

--What happened


select to_timestamp(1609534800000 / 1000) at TIME zone 'Pacific/Wake';
      timezone       
---------------------
 2021-01-02 09:00:00
(1 row)

--- Note you lopped off 9 hours and the returned timestamp has no time zone offset
--- so it is now local time 'America/Asuncion'

select date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(1609534800000 / 1000) at TIME zone 'Pacific/Wake');
     date_trunc      
---------------------
 2021-01-02 00:00:00

--- This gives it back a timezone offset.
--- Running the date_part on this then gets you the proper value.
select date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(1609534800000 / 1000) at TIME zone 'Pacific/Wake') at TIME zone 'Pacific/Wake';
 timezone        
------------------------
 2021-01-01 09:00:00-03
```

Comment: For the case #1 I found the problem. This is related to the DBeaver editor which displayed the time but converted using the timezone of my OS. Which is `America/New_York`. So the value now makes sense.

Comment: I've updated the post with an adtionnal question regarding time in Montreal. Could you explain me why it is not working ?

Comment: It is working, it is just in the local time zone 'America/Asuncion'. the only way you can change that is to `set time zone 'America/Montreal';